# How to display Sinhala Unicode characters in android app

Tags: android, unicode

I,m trying to show Sinhala Unicode characters in android app.
when i am using Samsung tabs or phones Unicode is running it on without problem.but it does not work on other phones or tab.cause there is no Sinhala Unicode.How to do this for an example i run this code on Samsung tab successfully.

```
Toast.makeText(this, "අන්තර්ජාල සම්බන්දතාවය තිබේ ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

but other phones or tab does n't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might need to have a Sinhalese font file (say, Sinhalese.ttf) in the directory `assets/fonts` in the root of your project.  You create a dummy text view because it has a method called `setTypeface`, which sets the font for next code:

```
import android.graphics.Typeface;

public class FontSampler extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.custom);  // a dummy text view
    Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                                      "fonts/Sinhalese.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(face);

    Toast.setView(tv).makeText(this, "අන්තර්ජාල සම්බන්දතාවය තිබේ ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

This way, even if an android phone doesn't have a font installed, then the font embedded in your app will serve. Hope this helps.

Comment: yep currently i'm doing this.but the problem is Typeface works only with textviews,buttons,edittext...etc.how work with Toast,Alert dialogs

Comment: @LahiruPrasanna please find the updated code line. I have sandwiched a method `setView` to Toast. It should do the necessity to show the font in Toast.

Comment: your code is helpful and i used this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#CustomToastView

Answer (score 1):

If you want to render the Both sinhala and English in same text box then use Iskolapota font file.And do the same as @Nonymous answer says. It works for me.[image]